# Java: Generics: Getting an object to type T from a generic method and accessing its methods

Tags: java, generics

```
    public interface MyMapperInterface<Y, Z> {

    Y map(Z zObject);

    }

    public class One{
    }

    public class Two{
    }


    public MapperOneTwo  implements MyMapperInterface<One, Two> {

        public One map(Two twoObject){
            //Based on properties of Two, a new One Object is created and returned.
        }

    }


public MapperThreeFour  implements MyMapperInterface<Three, Four> {

        public One map(Two twoObject){
            //Now for two other class, Three and Four, there is a new 
              mapper.
              Based on properties of Two, a new One Object is created and 
               returned.
        }

    }





    FactoryClass

    public class Factory {

        public <T> T getClassInstance(String params){
          if (params.equals("a")) { 
    return (T) new MapperOneTwo();
    } else if (params.equals("b")){
    return (T) new MapperThreeFour();
    }
    }

    }
```

**USAGE**
I have a handler class, which needed to map and pass along the other type. So i was hoping that the type(s) is passed into factory which then provides the respective mapper which then does its job and returns the object of the respective type. But the issue is that object returned now is of Object type and this handler class has to typecast it before passing it along further.

Is there a way to avoid type casting and still being able to create such a factory?

Thanks

Comment: In order for the calling method to do anything useful, the caller must know the type at compile time. Even when you have generic `T` in your method, if the caller doesn't know the type, it's going to keep that with a `Object` type. If the caller knows the type, then you should pass in the `Class` object of that type. Unless, all of them use a common interface, and caller just needs to know the interface.

Comment: Your edits just add more code and don't explain **why** you must do it this way. I suspect that your attempts with generics will never be able to solve your actual problem.

Comment: sorry. let me provide more details as to why i need generics in the interface

Comment: This example doesn't really make sense. If you know that `getClassInstance("a")` should return an instance of `ClassA`, then just use `new ClassA()` and don't use a factory method.

Comment: i have updated the OP. maybe it is more clear now

Comment: Again, you didn't specify how *exactly* you intend to use the object returned by the method. It's not going to work unless `One` and `Three` also implements a common interface, and `Two` and `Four` implements another common interface.

Comment: There is no way for a single method to return `MyMapperInterface<One, Two>` in some circumstances and `MyMapperInterface<Three, Four>` in other circumstances, unless you pass in Class objects, like `One.class` and `Two.class`.  Code cannot safely assume generic types correspond to different specific classes.

Comment: why the down vote? It seems to be a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following factory would solve the above issue, without the need to typecast:

```
public class Factory {


    public <Y, Z> Mapper<Y, Z> create(Class<Y> yClassType) {

        Mapper mapper;
        if (yClassType.equals(One.class)) {
            mapper = new MapperOneTwo();
        } else {
            //Handle default behaviour
        }
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> since the compiler thinks of it as Object class type

At runtime, `T` is just `Object`, so it has nothing to do with the compiler.  Actually, generics are mainly a compile time phenomenon, so the compiler actually *is* aware of generic types, but this goes away at runtime due to type erasure.

The standard factory patten uses coding to an interface, i.e. it returns an interface instance, behind which might be a particular implementation type.  So something like this should work for you:

```
public class Factory {
    public static MyInterface getClassInstance(String param) {
        switch (param) {
            case "a":
                return new MyClassA();
                break;

            case "b":
                return new MyClassB();
                break;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code, you may just use the instance of `MyInstance` without having to worry about the implementation.  If your code is not setup to use the pattern this way, you might want to do a refactor so that you can.

Comment: agreed but the issue is that my interface (MyInterface) is also generic. So it understands Type T until it is implemented and the actual class type is provided in place of T. So I end up with the same situation with the above solution also

Comment: Why does your interface need generics?

Comment: interface needs generics due to a design requirement. I updated the OP. thanks

Comment: Then I don't understand your design.  In the factory pattern, the underlying type returned is determined at runtime.